# Is Skype bot automated by Botium?

Tags: testing, botframework, chatbot

In my project we need to automate Skype bot. Can this be done using Botium? If yes, then please guide me. If no, please suggest any another open source tool?

Comment: Hi Ankit! I'm changing the tag on this, because the Botium people need to know. And AFAIK, Botium is still in development (I've been following them)

Comment: Thanks JJ_Wailes...much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Botium supports the [Directline3 interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-concepts) with an [own connector](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-directline3).
You can use this for testing your Skype bot with Botium.

Comment: Thanks @Florian Treml, I'll try this connector